# Groovy regex for any string between two fields

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I am using groovy regex:
*notification.ietf-restconf:notification.my-pma-device-notification:device-notification.device-notification.notification.**~/.***[A-Za-z]$/.entity-ref* for any string between notification and entity-ref but its not working.

What should be the regex for any string to exist between these two fields (groovy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few 'notification's in the string, assuming you mean the final one 'device-notification.notification'?

The following will capture at least one character between the strings.

```
def str = '''device-notification.device-notification.notification.CONTAINER-NAME.entity-ref'''  

def group = ( str =~ /(?<=device-notification\.notification\.)(.+)(?=\.entity-ref)/ ) 

assert 1 == group.count
assert 'CONTAINER-NAME' == group[0][0]​
```

Comment: _'{"aggs":{ "dedup": { "terms": {"script": "[doc[\u0027notification.ietf-restconf:notification.my-pma-device-notification:device-notification.entity-ref\u0027].value,doc[\u0027notification.ietf-restconf:notification.my-pma-device-notification:device-notification.device-notification.notification.*************.entity-ref\u0027].value, doc[\u0027alarm-identity\u0027].value].join(\u0027_\u0027)", "lang": "groovy", "valueType": "string", "null": true }, "aggs": { "dedup_docs": { "top_hits": { "size": 1 } } } } } } '_

Comment: This is my elastic query for which the starred (********) container name keeps on changing for different docs.  I want a regex for any string that can happen at the place if  starred (********)part.

Comment: Amended to accommodate periods

Comment: Does your full data actually have the unicode as per the pasted example e.g. \u0027 in it or is this how it's ended up after pasting here?

Comment: Its in unicode only and as we are using a curl command to fetch data from elastic hence its in unicode.

Comment: Its working on underscore (_) i.e CONTAINER_NAME but if we put a hyphen like CONTAINER-NAME. it didn't worked. Error -> Impossible to parse JSON response: SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 231.

Comment: Okay so it now matches at least 1 of anything

Comment: There is some problem with hyphen in the string. I am also looking for the solution. If you could also come up with some solution it will be a great help. Thanks in advance.